# How to make PostBackUrl only trigger when the button is clicked?

Tags: asp.net

I have a button with a PostBackUrl that navigates to a login page.  The postback works fine when I click the button and logs me in correctly.  However, after logging in successfully, if I hit the back button and click any link on the first page, it will do another postback.  So, I only want the postback to occur when the specific login button is clicked.

```
<asp:Button ID="login" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-block" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClientClick="formSubmit();" PostBackUrl="~/signin.aspx" />
```

My formSubmit() function just hashes my password.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use an HREF attribute like:

```
<asp:Button ID="login" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-block" runat="server" 
    Text="Login" OnClientClick="formSubmit();" href="~/signin.aspx" />
```